# Difficulty retrieving bitmaps from Hashmap

Tags: java, android, hashmap

I have stored video thumbnails in a hashmap this way:

```
HashMap cacheBitmap = new HashMap<String, Bitmap>(filesArry.length);
for(String string:filesArry) {
        cacheBitmap.put(string, ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(fpath + string, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND));
    }
```

The filesArry is a string array that has the video name of each thumbnail.

The problem is here inside the getView(...) method:

```
ImageView imageThumbnail = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.Thumbnail);
imageThumbnail.setImageBitmap(cacheBitmap.get(filesArry[position]));
```

It gives error under get(...) that says: "setImageBitmap (android.graphits.Bitmap) in ImageView cannot be applied to (java.lang.Object)

I tried to change Bitmap in `Hashmap<String, Bitmap>` into Drawable and into Object, but that didn't seem to fix the error.

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type parameters are missing in your declaration:

```
HashMap cacheBitmap = ...
```

Change it to:

```
HashMap<String, Bitmap> cacheBitmap = ...
```

Without this, the type is effectively `HashMap<Object, Object>`, that's why the `get` method returns an `Object` type instead of `Bitmap`. Fixing the declaration will fix your problem.

Going over step further, your declaration will be better using the interface type instead of the implementation:

```
Map<String, Bitmap> cacheBitmap = ...
```

Comment: OMG! you're right. Thanks a lot :) it says I can accept the answer in 6 minutes :( i will definitely.